# How to avoid loading a uicollectionview as sections

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

In my uicollectionview cells are loaded in sections. but the number of sections in the collectionview is 1. when sections are breaking there is a space between cells which i need to avoid.

[image]

```
func cellSize() -> CGSize {
    let collectionViewSize: CGSize = self.colorScrollCollectionView.frame.size
    return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize.width, height:  collectionViewSize.width * 0.35)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.colorArray.count * 5
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let cellSize = CGSize(width: self.cellSize().width, height: self.cellSize().height)
        return cellSize

}
```

Comment: share your code for `itemforSectionAt`

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return self.colorArray.count * 5
    }

Comment: please share some code. 
As per the above seems like cell size, spacing causing the issue.

Comment: I think the problem is with cell height.  when cell height changes the number of sections like above is changing. but it varies with the devices

Comment: share code @Amila for Lord's sake.